# How do i check whether connection details to MySql Server are valid?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I'm trying to write a function to check whether the connection details given on a Form are valid, so it returns True otherwise it returns False :

How can i achieve this ?

My code below :

```
 private bool checkConnectionSuccess(string host, string user, string pass, string dbname) {
        string strProvider = "Data Source=" + host + ";Database=" + dbname + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + pass;
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
        myConn.Open();  

        if (________) return true; else return false;


    }
```

What should I do in order to Check for the connection wether it was succeded based on the given details (user, pass, dbname, host)

Thankyou

Comment: Try to connect using the credentials supplied and if it fails provide the error message (or return true/false)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a try catch block:

```
private bool checkConnectionSuccess(string host, string user, string pass, string dbname)
{
   string connectionString = "Data Source=" + host + ";Database=" + dbname + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + pass;

   bool sucessful = true;

   using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection (connectionString))
   {
     try
     {
       conn.Open();
     }
     catch (MySqlException ex)
     {
       sucessful = false;
     }
   }
    return sucessful;
}
```

This is possible because MySQLConnection will likely fail on most exceptions, including if the credentials are wrong or the connection string is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Use a try-catch block, and set a flag telling whether or not it worked.

```
string strProvider = "Data Source=" + host + ";Database=" + dbname + ";User ID=" + user + ";Password=" + pass;
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);

bool success = true;

try
{
    myConn.open();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     success = false;
}

return success;
```